# How can I pass more than one argument to set attribute of object property in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Consider code below.

```
var book = {
    name: "JavaScript Test Book",
    edition: 3,
    year: 2014
};

Object.defineProperty(book, "info", {
    get: function() {
        return "\"" + this.name + "\" edition " + this.edition + " published on " + this.year;
    },
    set: function(info) {
        this.name = info[0];
        this.edition = info[1];
        this.year = info[2];
    }
});

console.log(book.info); //"JavaScript Test Book" edition 3 published on 2014

book.info = ["JavaScript Recipe", 1, 2015];

console.log(book.info); //"JavaScript Recipe" edition 1 published on 2015
```

So for my set attribute, the function is only accepting one argument, the array. And this is the only way i know to pass multiple arguments.

Is there any other ways to pass multiple arguments?
So my set function could be

```
set: function(name,edition,year) {
    this.name = name;
    this.edition = edition;
    this.year = year;
}
```

Comment: No, there's no way to pass multiple arguments -- it has to use the normal assignment syntax, which is `destination = value`.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. What would the syntax look like when you're actually setting the property value?

Comment: Why don't you just use a new method, `object.setInfo(name, edition, year)`?

Comment: Weird question. `set` is for a single property. I imagine you could call `book.info = {name: 'Stack Explosion', edition: '1st', year: '2015'}`

Comment: You could make the argument look like the output of `get`: `book.info = '"Javascript Test Book" edition 3 published on 2014'`. Use a regular expression to parse it.

Comment: @Barmar so same way get attribute function cannot accept any argument?

Comment: Right. Getters and setters just let you customize the behavior of assignment and access syntax, they don't let you change the basic syntax.

Comment: @Barmar I see, i was just curious since this type of getter/setter attribute was new to me. So thought if there's any way we could do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you quite get the purpose of getters/setters. It's not supposed to work like a function, even though that's how it's implemented. It's supposed to work like a normal property but with a bit of extra control, like the ability to reject a value.

For what you are doing, you should consider continuing to use a function.

Here's a better use of properties:

```
var book = {
    name: "JavaScript Test Book",
    edition: 3,
    _year: 2014 // it'd be best to use a closure to ensure
                // third-party code doesn't have access to
                // your backing store
};

Object.defineProperty(book, "year", {
    get: function() {
        return this._year;
    },
    set: function(v) {
        // Only assign the value if it's numeric
        if ( !isNaN(parseFloat(v)) && isFinite(v) )
            this._year = v;
        else
            throw 'Expecting a numeric value'; // be nice and make debugging easier
    }
});
```

When defining your properties, it's important to follow the [principle of least astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). If I assign an array to a property, I'd expect to get to get that array back when I access the property. Assigning an array to a property and getting a string back is *very* astonishing and will certainly lead to very hard to diagnose bugs.

In general, I'd strongly caution against ever mutating a value in a setter. If the user is assigning a value to the property, it is far, far better to reject a malformed value than to try to fix it or change it somehow.

Imagine how livid you'd be if you ran the following code but got back 0 results:

```
var u = new User();
u.FirstName = "Jon-Paul";
otherUsers.push( u );
// ... a thousand lines later ...
var JPs = otherUsers.filter(function(u){ return u.FirstName === "Jon-Paul"; });
```

What you didn't know was that the author of the User object opted to mutate the `FirstName` property based on some internal business rules from your original value to "JONPAU". Imagine how difficult this would be to debug. Now imagine how easy it'd be if you just got a simple error when you assigned the `FirstName` property, something like: `Error: FirstName must be all caps, contain characters A-Z and be no longer than 6 characters.`